# Cannot alter User Login/Register Page

Tags: templates, magento

I am making a Magento template for 1.6 and I am trying to adjust the user login and register pages.

I have copied the "customer" folder from the default template but the changes I make to register don't seem to affect the site.

If i make changes to other files under the customer folder, like the dashboard or the address book, they work, but for some reason the forms just don't want to.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files site in the persistent directory under

```
{basedir}/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form
```

You'll find the login.phtml and register.phtml files there.

Comment: Thanks so much. Do you know why they have a persistent folder?

Comment: I believe it's to do with the persistent shopping cart, which was introduced in Magento CE 1.6. The Magento team have probably added the new functionality and, to provide backwards compatibility, they have kept the old functionality as well...that's a complete guess.